# Getting the debian source from java maven projejct

Tags: packaging

I have an open source project which was built in Java maven. In order to build a debian package a bebian source files are required as tarballs. How I can get those files from java maven?. I would appreciate any suggestion!.

Thanks
N.Gh

Comment: Are you asking how to use the 'tar' command to create a tarball?

Comment: No, I want to generate debian source from maven source. Thanks

Comment: Exactly which step of creating the package are you stuck on? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I'm at the beginning, I want to have  orig.tar file with all dependencies.

Comment: Go to the Maven website. On the Maven website, look for the 'download' link. Look for the Source .tar.gz archive. That's the source tarball. Download it. Unpack it from .tar.gz to plain .tar. Rename it.

Comment: Hi, this is not the answer of my question. I don't want to download Maven!. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: You want the source code of Maven, but you don't want to download the source code of Maven? Perhaps your question is not clear enough yet.

Comment: I hope someone will understand the question and give me a reasonable answer. The question is not about installing maven it is about packaging to debian  a project build using maven.

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question. As you can see, it may be clear to you...but it must be clear to us. The Debian Java team (https://wiki.debian.org/Java ) has done a lot of work packaging with Maven. You might get some good advice there, too.